# Repeated failed tests for: Given object and key, return array containing elements within the array, located at the given key, that meet condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

[The Link (you'll have to sign up)](http://prep.hackreactor.com/courses/118569/lectures/1732222)

While my code returns the expected output, I keep getting failed tests for the fallowing problem. Is the problem with the test or with my code?

**The Problem...**

Given an object and a key, Write a function that returns an array containing the elements within the array, located at the given key, that meet a condition.

- If array is empty, return an empty array.
- If array does not meet condition, return an empty array.
- If the property at given key is not an array, return an empty array.
- If there is no property at the key, return an empty array.

**Condition:** elements less than 100.

**The code**

```
// expected output -> [20, 50, 0, 16] 

var obj = {
  key: [150, 20, 50, 100, 0, 16]
};



function getElementsLessThan100AtProperty(obj, key) {
  var arr = [];

  for (var i in obj.key){
    if(obj.key[i] < 100){
      arr.push(obj.key[i]);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

getElementsLessThan100AtProperty(obj, 'key')// [20, 50, 0, 16]
```

**Failed Test Message**

```
should return an array containing all the elements less than 100 in the array located at key

Expected to equal 20,50,0,16.
```

What gives?? Am I missing something here or is the test wrong?

Comment: Looks like the test is at fault to me. You should double check if the expected output is an array.

Comment: Show the code of your test and remote `key` argument no usage.

Comment: That's what I thought about the argument 'key' as well, it's not necessary. The code of the test's output isn't accessible. The test does expect an array. If I hard code the function's return with the expected output as an array, that part of the test passes but the empty array test obviously fails. When I  use an if statement and return either a hardcoded array or an empty array it fails. It's bizarre??

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function that returns an array, you need to save that array to something.

So in your case, your last line should be something like:

`var arr = getElementsLessThan100AtProperty(obj, 'key');`

`arr` now holds the filtered array (or possibly empty array, if the conditions aren't met).